# POE ethernet passthrough microcontroller

Tags: microcontrollers

I'm looking for a build your own or mod hack something like a POE ethernet passthrough that powers an Arduino IoT controller. I understand that what ever I am using will need it's own dedicated IP stream but given how small some things have gotten I though a small female to female ethernet device that carries a light or temp sensor would be neat. Just tinker stuff.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  We are going to need more detail on your exact issue if we are going to help you.  Please [edit] your question to specify exactly what research you have done so far and what the precise problem is that you are having.  Thanks!

Comment: It won’t be that small, but there are PoE-powered Ethernet switches which can then themselves power other devices over PoE (search for “PoE switch passthrough”). Note that they will usually require PoE+ (802.3at) input and deliver PoE (802.3af) output. You could then connect your device to one of the ports.